# Definition of Complex Integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm studying the complex integral, I have the following exercise:
 $\int_{C}\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}dz$, where $C$ is the Jordan curve formed by the union of $y=x^2-2$ and $y=-x^2+2$.

Here partial fractions does not work, I tried to parameterize but I do not get anything useful to perform the respective calculations.

Comment: Do you know/are you allowed to use the Residue Theorem?

Comment: Can you parametrize your curves (path).

Comment: z=x+iy, then I parametrize x=cos t and y = sin t

Comment: Don't those curves form two halves of parabolas?

Comment: @Cat Yes, those curves form two halves of parabolas.